# How to call some functions in the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing

I'm wondering what is the best way to run some functions in the same time.
I wrote a Python module that runs 3 instances of Firefox with Selenium webdriver, that should load the same page in each one of them.

my code looks like :

```
url = "http://google.com"
firefox1 = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox2 = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox3 = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox1.get(url)
firefox2.get(url)
firefox3.get(url)
```

Selenium is very(!) slow, and each one of the page loading takes about a 30-60 secs.
I want to run all of the `firefox*.get(url)` parallel.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: pass ur urls as parameters, see the selenium parametrization techniques and probably use selenium grid for parallel testing

Comment: What is the objective of loading the same URL in three different instances?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would guess it's just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @mjohnsonengr why guess?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Does it change anything to the problem if he's using different url?

Answer (score 1):

if its not that big process, you can use thread (although that wouldn't be a perfect parallel, due to python's GIL but still would do your job to some extent)

2) you can use asynchronous programming for this purpose. if its python3 you can use inbuilt library `asyncio`

here is sample program(I've not tested but it should give you an idea about asyncio)

```
import asyncio

def func1(args):
    print('func1')
def func2(args):
    print('func2')
def func3(args):
    print('func3')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
flist = [func1(args), func2(args), func3(args)]
w = asyncio.wait(flist)
loop.run_until_complete(w)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of using asyncio to achieve the result that Dan wants

Comment: Good job. Welcome to stackoverflow!